# Terraform, how to provision droplet with salt-minion (masterless)

Tags: vagrant, saltstack, terraform

I've managed to get a local development server running with *Vagrant*, provisioning it with *Salt* in a *masterless configuration*. Now, I'm trying to take advantage of the existing salt states to provision a production server, but so far haven't figure out how to do it.

I've managed to created a *Digital Ocean droplet* with *Terraform*, and now I would like to provision it with *Salt*, ideally using the same `.sls` files used to provision the development machine. In Vagrant, this is rather trivial, as one just needs to declare it in `Vagrantfile`, like this:

```
config.vm.provision :salt do |salt|
salt.minion_config = "salt/minion"
salt.run_highstate = true
```

Afterwards, it just a question of creating a [state tree](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html#bootstrap-salt-minion) pointing to our state files, where we declare the packages we would like our machine to be provisioned with, the files that we would like to sync, etc.

With `Terraform` however, there seems to be no similar way to do it. Terraform's [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html) on provisioners is rather scarce. Other than invoking a Chef Client, or declaring the files we want to copy directly on a `provisioner`, or invoke a script, I couldn't find any reference on how to invoke Salt to provision an instance. I wonder if it's even possible?

Here's my `servers.tf`:

```
module "hosting" {
    source                  = "./modules/server"
    droplet_count           = 1
    droplet_image           = "ubuntu-14-04-x64"
    droplet_region          = "nyc2"
    droplet_size            = "512mb"       
    dns_record_domain       = "site.org"
    droplet_backups         = true
    droplet_ipv6            = true
    droplet_privatenet      = true
}
```

The following is my `droplet.tf` file:

```
provider "digitalocean" {
    token           = "${var.do_token}"
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "droplet" {
    image           = "${var.droplet_image}"
    name            = "${var.droplet_type}-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
    region          = "${var.droplet_region}"
    size            = "${var.droplet_size}"
    ssh_keys        = ["${var.ssh_fingerprint}"]
    backups         = "${var.droplet_backups}"
    ipv6            = "${var.droplet_ipv6}"
    private_networking  = "${var.droplet_privatenet}"
}

resource "digitalocean_ssh_key" "default" {
    name            = "rsa-key-nopass"
    public_key      = "${file("./.ssh/rsa-key-nopass")}"
}
```

And finally, my `dns_records.tf` file:

```
provider "cloudflare" {
    email   = "${var.cf_email}"
    token   = "${var.cf_token}" 
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "ipv4" {
    count   = "${var.droplet_count}"
    domain  = "${var.dns_record_domain}"
    name    = "${element(digitalocean_droplet.droplet.*.name, count.index)}"
    value   = "${element(digitalocean_droplet.droplet.*.ipv4_address, count.index)}"
    type    = "A"
    ttl     = 3600
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "ipv6" {
    count   = "${var.droplet_count}"
    domain  = "${var.dns_record_domain}"
    name    = "${element(digitalocean_droplet.droplet.*.name, count.index)}"
    value   = "${element(digitalocean_droplet.droplet.*.ipv6_address, count.index)}"
    type    = "AAAA"
    ttl     = 3600
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**UPDATE**

I've added the following two `provisioner` blocks:

```
provisioner "file" {
    source = "../salt"
    destination = "/etc/salt"
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      # install and configure salt-minion
      "curl -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com -o install_salt.sh",
      "sudo sh install_salt.sh",
      "salt '*' state.apply"
    ]
}
```

The `/salt` directory is being copied succesfully into `/etc/salt` and salt is being installed as well, but I'm getting a `Script exited with non-zero exit status: 127` message before any state is applied. Why exactly, I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling `salt-minion` to look for the state tree in the local file system and runing our `salt-minion` with the [`salt-call`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/cli/salt-call.html) command seems to do the trick:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
    # install salt-minion
    "wget -O - http://bootstrap.saltstack.org | sudo sh"
    ]
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
         # tell salt-minion to look for the state tree in 
         # the local file system, with the --local flag.
        "salt-call --local state.highstate"
    ]
}
```

On the `minion` file, tell salt to look at the local file directory instead of the `salt master`, which is the default configuration (this will run the minion in masterless mode). One also needs to point the root directory for the base environment to where our top.sls is located:

```
# Tell salt-minion to not look for a master. 
# Default configuration is file_client: remote

file_client: local

# Set the root directory for the base environment 
# to where our top.sls is located.

file_roots:
    base:
    - /etc/salt/roots
```

Answer (score 1):

I've published an [example to setup a Salt master with Terraform on DigitalOcean, and from there to start some minions](https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples). Beware that some parts of the example assume that terraform ist started on a Windows machine (but not the ones listed below).

The essential bits from [`saltmaster.tf`](https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples/blob/master/saltmaster.tf):

1. copy your SLS files to the new server using terraform

   ```
   provisioner "file" {
       source = "master/srv"
       destination = "/"
   }
   ```
2. copy a startup file to the new server

   ```
   provisioner "file" {
       source = "complete-bootstrap.sh"
       destination = "/tmp/complete-bootstrap.sh"
   }
   ```

   The contents of the complete-bootstrap.sh:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -x
   # create the minion's key pair and accept it on the master
   mkdir -p /etc/salt/pki/master/minions
   salt-key --gen-keys=minion --gen-keys-dir=/etc/salt/pki/minion
   mkdir -p /etc/salt/pki/minion
   cp /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pub /etc/salt/pki/master/minions/master
   service salt-master start
   salt-call -l debug state.highstate
   service salt-minion start
   ```
3. install salt minion and master

   ```
   provisioner "remote-exec" {
       inline = [
       # install salt-minion and salt-master, but don't start services
       "curl -L https://bootstrap.saltstack.com | sh -s -- -M -X -A localhost",
       # work around possible missing executable flag
       "cat /tmp/complete-bootstrap.sh | sh -s"
       ]
   }
   ```

This should give you a running Salt master at DO started from Terraform.

Comment: Hi @ahus1, thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am already familiarized with your tutorial and have actually been studying it :-) I've been attemping a masterless configuration though. I start by copying the full directory where I've my `.sls` files (as well as other files to be copied by salt itself, mostly `.conf` files). I do this in a `provisioner "file"` block, much as you do above. After that, I attempt to install and configure salt minion in a `provisioner "remote-exec"` block, but I'm getting a `Script exited with non-zero exit status: 127` (please see update above).

Comment: @pierrebonbon the 127 error code indicates that the program in the first line of your script hasn't been found. I also happens when script is encoded windows style (CRLF) instead of unix style (LF). BTW: i don't see any remote-exec block in your question (yet).

Comment: I updated it just now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, for posterity I'd like to mention that I contributed the salt-masterless provisioner into Terraform:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/14720

It has been merged and deployed in the v0.10.2 release. For whatever reason it looks like the doc is not yet uploaded onto the website, however you can access the raw doc file here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/commit/08670763aa9b3f0a22ebf73f859f3b73a36351e2#diff-29ecd8bdf326c94e4f13d83497bc63e8

It should be similar in usage to the Packer salt-masterless provisioner (I can't post another link due to reputation).

That's where I copied the code from initially.

Comment: Great work, thanks! The documentation on the salt-masterless provisioner is already available on the official Terraforms's website: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/salt-masterless.html